# Find weather using Java

Tags: java, weather, weather-api

I was wondering if there is a way to find the weather of specific town/city using Java. I have heard of Google Weather API but that has not yielded any results. I also have heard about using an .xml feed for finding the weather but where can I find that? Therefore, I have two questions, Is there a way to find the weather to find using Java and am I correct about the .xml?

Comment: A quick search reveals a [Java Weather API](http://code.google.com/p/java-weather-api/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Weather API appears to be no more:

http://thenextweb.com/google/2012/08/28/did-google-just-quietly-kill-private-weather-api/

But you can use others such as

http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/

Once you have your XML (or JSON) you can parse it as described here:

[Using Java to extract data from google Weather API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487508/using-java-to-extract-data-from-google-weather-api)

Comment: The link you have provided shows how to extract from google Weather API but is it still the same concept to extract from the API you have provided?

Comment: The various APIs will probably deliver XML or JSON: in which case the source is largely irrelevant: you just need to handle/process the result you get.

Comment: So, wunderground will not not provide XML or JSON?

Comment: @gekkostate I've worked with the Wunderground API before on iOS. It provided JSON and it was very easy to use -- only downside is that it isn't free to use beyond messing around as a developer.

I'm a bit surprised that the Google Weather API was pulled, and relieved -- I was thinking about using it for my project only months prior.

Answer (score 3):

you can use openweathermap api for this.
Go to this link and download api and you can also see some examples to use it
http://openweathermap.org/api